# How to unzip file in server(linux) with php code

Tags: php, linux, server, unzip

I tried a lot of code, But not work.

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];

if (isset($file))
{
   echo "Unzipping " . $file . "<br>";
   if(system('unzip '. $file.' -d dirtounzipto ' ))
   {echo 'GGWP';}else{echo 'WTF';}

   exit;
}?>
```

How can i unzip in server. with "system" or "shell_exec" code.

Comment: I smell shell command injection...

Answer (score 4):

```
$zip_filename = "test.zip";
$zip_extract_path = "/";
try{
$zip_obj = new ZipArchive;
            if (file_exists($zip_filename)) {
                $zip_stat = $zip_obj->open($zip_filename);
                if ($zip_stat === TRUE) {
                    $res = $zip_obj->extractTo($zip_extract_path);
                    if ($res === false) {

                            throw new Exception("Error in extracting file on server.");

                    }
                    $zip_obj->close();


                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Error in open file");
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("zip file not found for extraction");
            }
}catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make good use of PHP's [`ZipArchive` library](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php):

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Version requirement: PHP >= 5.2.0, PECL zip >= 1.1.0

---

**UPDATE** To create the destination path automatically, you can use:

```
mkdir($path, 0755, true);
```

which create the folders required automatically.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has built-in extensions for dealing with compressed files. There should be no need to use system calls for this. ZipArchive[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) is one option.

```
// assuming file.zip is in the same directory as the executing script.
$file = 'file.zip';

// get the absolute path to $file
$path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

//folder name as per zip file name
$foldername = basename($file, ".zip");

mkdir($foldername, 0755, true);
$path = $path . "/" . $foldername;

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract it to the path we determined above
  $zip->extractTo($path);
  $zip->close();
  echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
} else {
  echo "Doh! I couldn't open $file";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.it work, but it not create a folder. Got a file name like this "fodername\subfolder\filename.php".

Comment: @Apb how does this answer differ from mine?

Comment: @Raptor when I said my answer is different than yours?